# Regex how to replace vowels of certain words

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I am making a filter to block bad words and I am looking for a way to search a block of text for a word then replace the vowels of that word with * Is there a way to do this with a regex expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

You could `.join("|")` an Array of bad words into a string like `bad|awful|sick` where the *pipe* `|` will act as a RegExp list of **alternatives**.

```js
const text = "This is nice and I really like it so much!";
const bad = ["much", "like", "nice"].join("|");
const fixed = text.replace(new RegExp(`\\b(${bad})\\b`, "ig"), m => m.replace(/[aeiou]/ig, "*"));

console.log(fixed);
```

To replace the **entire word** with `*` use:

```js
text.replace(new RegExp(`\\b(${bad})\\b`, "ig"), m => "*".repeat(m.length));
```

If you want to also target compound words (i.e: *`unlike`* given *`like`* is a bad word) than use simply `RegExp(bad, "ig")` without the `\b` Word Boundary assertion.

Also, if necessary [escape your bad words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) if some contain RegExp special characters like `.` etc...

Comment: that's not replacing just the vowels :p - use `=> m.replace(/[aeiou]/gi, '*')`